# Python list index out of range in recursive funciton

Tags: python, recursion

I have this homework problem in recursion: checking for valid parentheses. The question asks me to write a function that gets a string and a counter as an input and return whether the parentheses were opened and closed properly.

```
def is_valid_paren(s, cnt=0):

    lst1 = list(s)

    if lst1 == [] and cnt ==0:
        return True

    if lst1[0] == '(':
        cnt+=1
        return is_valid_paren(lst1[1:], cnt)

    elif lst1[0] == ')':
        cnt-=1
        return is_valid_paren(lst1[1:], cnt)

    else:
        return is_valid_paren(lst1[1:], cnt)
```

This is my code, however I keep getting a list index out of range error when I try running it on some strings. Any help on why I get this error message would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: This is unrelated to the main logic error that leads to the exception, but unless you intend a string like `"))(("` to count as "valid", you probably want to check that `cnt` is greater than zero in the `elif` branch, before you recurse.

Answer (score 3):

Did you notice that your function never returns `False`?

It should return `False` when `lst1` is empty and `cnt != 0`. You never check for that, so you get an error when you try to use `lst1[0]` in this case.

```
def is_valid_paren(s, cnt=0):

    lst1 = list(s)

    if lst1 == []:
        return cnt == 0

    if lst1[0] == '(':
        cnt += 1
    elif lst1[0] == ')':
        cnt -= 1

    return is_valid_paren(lst1[1:], cnt)
```